# apache redirect to https://www

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I have the following code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.sample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

When I access `http://sample.com`,redirected to `https://www.sample.com`.

When I access `http://www.sample.com`, redirected to `https://www.sample.com`.

When I access `https://sample.com`, can not redirect.

Comment: Where did you put the above? In the ``VirtualHost`` for port 80? Global scope outside of all ``VirtualHost`` definitions?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton inside `VirtualHost`.

Comment: If you have only stuck that inside of the ``VirtualHost`` for port 80, then it will never get applied to HTTPS requests. Do you also have a version in ``VirtualHost`` for port 443?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I use aws elb to transfer access to port443 to port80. Also in this case, is setting for port 443 necessary?